# How to make persistent buffer list above frame like in vim powerline

Tags: buffers, vim-emulation, powerline

I want to implement behavior similar to mine vim config, where all basic info was below the main frame, like modes, position in file, changes, but above the frame is list of all buffers, with separated by color active buffer for active window. Is it possible to do somehow? thx. Can you suggest some plugins or scripts implementing similar behavior?

Comment: Have you already look at `tabbar` (which uses the `header-line-format`), and are you dealing with hundreds of buffers or just a few?  I've seen some creative ideas that also use the `frame-title-format` to reflect certain information.

Comment: There is the header line, but it spans *windows*, not the entire frame. So, once you have more than one vertical split open, the illusion of a contiguous bar will be gone.

Comment: Cannot get your meaning, maybe you can post an image, and try `speedbar`, not sure whether this is you want or not. And I think you misunderstand the concepts of frame and window.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `C-x C-b` (`list-buffers`)? That gives you a list of buffers in another window. It will remain visible, depending on what keys you use to access the listed buffers. `?` in that window tells you what keys are available:

```
Buffer Menu mode defined in ‘buff-menu.el’:
Major mode for Buffer Menu buffers.
The Buffer Menu is invoked by the commands C-x C-b,
M-x buffer-menu, and M-x buffer-menu-other-window.
See ‘buffer-menu’ for a description of its contents.

In Buffer Menu mode, the following commands are defined:

q    Remove the Buffer Menu from the display.
RET  Select current line’s buffer in place of the buffer menu.
o    Select that buffer in another window,
 so the Buffer Menu remains visible in its window.
V    Select current line’s buffer, in View mode.
M-x Buffer-menu-view-other-window  Select that buffer in
 another window, in view-mode.
C-o  Make another window display that buffer.
m    Mark current line’s buffer to be displayed.
v    Select current line’s buffer.
 Also show buffers marked with m, in other windows.
1    Select that buffer in full-frame window.
2    Select that buffer in one window, together with the
 buffer selected before this one in another window.
M-s a C-s    Incremental search in the marked buffers.
M-s a C-M-s  Isearch for regexp in the marked buffers.
M-s a C-o Show lines matching regexp in the marked buffers.
t    visit-tags-table this buffer.
~    Clear modified-flag on that buffer.
s    Mark that buffer to be saved, and move down.
C-k  Mark that buffer to be deleted, and move down.
C-d  Mark that buffer to be deleted, and move up.
x    Delete or save marked buffers.
u    Remove all marks from current line.
 With prefix argument, also move up one line.
DEL  Back up a line and remove marks.
%    Toggle read-only status of buffer on this line.
g    Update the list of buffers.
T    Toggle whether the menu displays only file buffers.
b    Bury the buffer listed on this line.
```