# Recent buffers bar

Tags: buffers

Is there a solution to have last visited buffers in a single one-line bar?
That I can see my last, lets say, five buffers all the time and press `M-1`, `M-2`, .. to switch to them fast.

[The TabBarMode plugin](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode) is something I tried, but it spawns the bar in every buffer, and do not sort buffers in the necessary order.

Comment: Similar question asked recently, but not yet answered: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14366/115

Comment: I agree that the question is similar to the one linked in the previous comment, which I have already commented to (in that other thread) regarding the need for a dedicated buffer or a dedicated frame/buffer to manage buffers.  Provided there is a dedicated frame/buffer to managing buffers, then `yes` it would be possible to have select buffers from the `buffer-list` appear as candidates.  However, that is not what the original poster truly wants -- although it may be a viable/palatable alternative.

Comment: You are duplicating your posts (several, now) on both this site and StackOverflow. **Please don't do that.** Please choose one or the other site.